# Is it possible to create parent and child records in single Salesforce create call of PHP toolkit?

Tags: php

In the official documentation there are examples of how to do it in Java and C# but there are no examples of how to do it in PHP using Salesforce PHP Toolkit:

See paragraph "create() and Foreign Keys" here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm

Example of create call using PHP toolkit:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_(Enterprise)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: for the External_ID_Field__c its required same name in both objects? or we can use any field which is carrying same value in both object

Comment: Yes, you have to put the same value for External_ID_Field__c on both objects. You can only use fields which are marked as external ID fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long ago I saw this solution on the developerforce message boards, you have to modify the PHP toolkit so that the _convertToAny() function found in SforceBaseClient.php looks like this:

```
protected function _convertToAny($fields) {
    $anyString = '';
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        if($value instanceOf stdclass || $value instanceOf SObject) {
            $anyString = $anyString . '<' . $key . ' xmlns="">';
            $anyString = $anyString . '<type xmlns="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">' . $value->type . '</type>';
            $anyString = $anyString . $this->_convertToAny($value->fields);
            $anyString = $anyString . '</'. $key . '>';
        }else{
            $anyString = $anyString . '<' . $key . '>' . $value . '</' . $key . '>';
        }
    }
    return $anyString;
}
```

Now you can do cascade inserts like so:

```
// create SOAP connect
$mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection($pathToPartnerWsdl);
$mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($username, $password);

// create a Contact
$contactObj = new SObject();
$contactObj->type = 'Contact';
$contactObj->fields = array(
    'FirstName' => 'Some',
    'LastName' => 'Guy',
    'Email' => 'example@example.com'
);

// create an Account
$accountObj = new SObject();
$accountObj->type = 'Account';  
$accountObj->fields = array(
    'Name' => 'This is an Account',
    'External_ID_Field__c' => 'XXYYZZ'
);

// create a reference (this can only have the External ID field, trust me)
$accountRef = new SObject();
$accountRef->type = 'Account';  
$accountRef->fields = array(
    'External_ID_Field__c' => 'XXYYZZ'
);

$contactObj->fields['Account'] = $accountRef;

// insert the sObjects (this only works if the parent comes first)
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($accountObj, $contactObj));

print_r($createResponse);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tomorrow I'll try this solution. If it works I'll accept and +1 your answer.

Comment: It does not work. Error message shows up: SoapFault: Element {}item invalid at this location in SoapClient->__call(). The error comes from SforceBaseClient.php, function _create, return statement. I'm using the version 20.0 of PHP Toolkit. Another question is, what I'm supposed to put instead of XXYYZZ string? Thank you!

Comment: I've tested this sample myself, it definitely works.

Sounds like you are providing the enterprise WSDL to the partner client. If you want to use the enterprise WSDL you need to change the way the SObjects are declared in this code (see the force.com PHP toolkit samples for help).

'XXYYZZ' is the external ID value that the records are linking on, you just put whatever you want your external ID to be here.

Comment: Ok, the error disappeared using the partner WSDL. Now I have the following error: "SoapFault: INVALID_FIELD: No such column 'External_ID_Field__c' on entity 'Account'" Should I create this column and refresh WSDL to solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Well, I've just done it and now another error appears: SoapFault: Unexpected element {urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com}type during simple type deserialization in SoapClient->__call() Again, the error comes from SforceBaseClient.php, function _create, return statement. What I'im doing wrong? Are you also using the 20.0 version of toolkit? Thanks!

Comment: As stated above, I am using version 20.0 of the toolkit. All I did was create the external ID field (make sure it's marked as an an external ID), make the toolkit code change and then run the exact code above.

Comment: Ok, that error dissapeared. I have done all you said. But now salesforce returns me two errors: For the first object returns "record type missing for: Account" and for the second "Foreign key external ID: 1234 not found for field External_ID_Field__c in entity Account" But now I clearly see that all your code does work fine. Now I guess is just a matter of setting correct values on object Account Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear you are making progress, any confusion might be because I had assumed you already read the documentation around External ID fields. Also, make sure that the parent is before any children in the array you insert (just added that comment to my code).